# private network - preallocate units off the chain and release those in specific time intervals

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, private-blockchain

is there a way to pre-allocate `x amount` of ether units off the chain - not through `genesis.json`  - and release `y amount` every `z amount` of time in the private network ?

Comment: A smart contract where you send X Ether and it does the distribution? But it can't do it in the background, it has to be called whenever something needs to be done

Comment: that would solve distribution, what about off the chain preallocation without the need of genesis.json alloc:? any suggestions here ?

Comment: It's not really designed to work this way. Who are you releasing it to? What's the conditions for doing it this way? If you can define these parameters, then you could create a smart contract that holds ether, which people can call after certain blocks and if they meet the conditions then they get ether transferred to them.

Comment: to make a transfer of some amount of money you have to cryptographically lock the transaction into the blockchain and cryptographically tie blocks one to another, so, no, no way of releasing money off chain. Otherwise the whole cryptocurrency concept would be worth nothing

Comment: clarification: I do not want to release it off the chain. I want to preallocate off the chain. Release those preallocated funds in predefined intervals or based on the specific conditions and of course include all those transactions in the blockchain. smart contract probably would be able to somehow satisfy my requirement though, I am not sure about preallocation (preferrably directly in the smart contract address)